# How to parse item that consiste of multiple pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a web spider that looks like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = LinkExtractor(unique=True).extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
        if '/item/' in link.url:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse_item)
        else:
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse)

def parse_item(self, response):
    res = MyItem()
    res['Param1'] = response.xpath('_get_param_1')
    res['Param2'] = response.xpath('_get_param_2')
    res['Param3'] = response.xpath('_get_param_3')
    yield res
```

My problem is that each item has additional information on other page so I need to modify my code like this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    res = MyItem()
    res['Param1'] = response.xpath('_get_param_1')
    res['Param2'] = response.xpath('_get_param_2')
    res['Param3'] = response.xpath('_get_param_3')

    new_url = response.url + '/more_info/'
    # Goto new_url
    res['Param4'] = response.xpath('_get_param_4')
    res['Param5'] = response.xpath('_get_param_5')

    yield res
```

But I don't know how to do it with scrappy.

UPD: What exactly I need.
I need to parse a site with different apartments for rent. Each apartment has such url like `site.com/item/id12345678` this page has `price`, `address` and some other information useful for me and I can parse them as usual with `scrappy` But also the same apartment has some additional information like `sellers_phone` on second page `site.com/item/id12345678/more_info`. And finally I want to get a list of records with:

```
id, price, address, sellers_phone
```

Comment: Please give a more concrete example of what you want to achieve. If you need to browse many pages, say, in a queue, then you may need to use scrapy `callback` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

Comment: @Arnaud I updated first post

Answer (score 1):

That question is very large. IIUC, you need to define a "journey" i.e. a few urls to visit in order to collect all potential information of one appartment. You want to use `scrapy` and that's a good choice.

This below is a kinda pseudo-code. Not intended to work, but to give you an idea of how `scrapy` can help in your case. Strongly inspired from the [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) though. The idea is to use `callback` argument in order to define what next action you'll want to do, step by step (url by url).

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = [
        "site.com/item/id12345678", 
        "site.com/item/id9786314", 
        ...]

    res = MyItem()

    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(u, 
                                 callback=self.parse_page_1)

    def parse_page_1(self, response):
        res['Param1'] = response.xpath('_get_param_1')
        res['Param2'] = response.xpath('_get_param_2')
        res['Param3'] = response.xpath('_get_param_3')
        yield scrapy.Request(url_more_info,  # call the page with more info
                            callback=self.parse_page_2)

    def parse_page_2(self, response):
        res['Param4'] = response.xpath('_get_param_4')
        res['Param5'] = response.xpath('_get_param_5')
        yield res
```

Answer (score 1):

To put together scraped data in the right manner, I suggest you to use the `Request.meta` attribute to pass values to the requests.

From the [official guide](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> In some cases you may be interested in passing arguments to those callback functions so you can receive the arguments later, in the second callback. You can use the Request.meta attribute for that.
>
> Here’s an example of how to pass an item using this mechanism, to populate different fields from different pages:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

With this, you can easily associate the outer pages to the inner pages even in asynchronous mode, making easy to export results the right way.